# PostgreSQL not filtering on a boolean column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table customer, that has following columns:

```
create table customer
(
    id                                 bigserial.              primary key,
    external_id                        text                                      not null,
    name                               text,
    default_sender_address             bigint
        constraint customer_default_sender_address_fkey
            references address_book,
    information                        text,
    updated_by                         text,
    created_by                         text,
    created_at                         timestamp with time zone default now(),
    updated_at                         timestamp with time zone default now(),
    external_subcustomer               text                     default ''::text not null,
    type                               text,
    credit_blocked                     boolean                  default false    not null,
    mandatory_subcustomer              boolean                  default false    not null,
    external_uuid                       uuid
        constraint customer_external_uuid_key
            unique,
    external_parent_uuid                uuid,
    is_deleted                         boolean                  default false    not null,
);
```

I have a query where I would like to fetch all duplicates that have `false` value for `is_deleted` column:

```
SELECT
  a.id as customer_id,
  a.external_id,
  a.external_subcustomer,
  a.name,
  a.type,
  a.external_uuid,
  a.is_deleted 
FROM
  customer a 
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        external_id,
        external_subcustomer,
        COUNT(*) 
      FROM
        customer 
      WHERE
        is_deleted = false 
        AND 
        (
          external_subcustomer = '' 
          OR external_subcustomer is null
        )
      GROUP BY
        external_id,
        external_subcustomer 
      HAVING
        COUNT(*) > 1 
    )
    b 
    ON a.external_id = b.external_id 
    AND a.external_subcustomer = b.external_subcustomer 
ORDER BY
  a.external_id;
```

When I execute this query I get all the duplicates, but also the ones that have `is_deleted` set to `true`. Why are those not filtered out?
What am I doing wrong with this query?

Comment: If I'm following it is because `ON a.external_id = b.external_id  ...` where `b.external_id` represents rows that have  `a.external_id`  duplicated for `is_deleted=false` and also have one or more rows where `is_deleted=true`. You might add a `WHERE a.is_deleted=false` to the outer query.

Comment: yeah, having the where on the outer query did the trick